# Android Emulator doesn't play sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've get the feeling that this should just work, by what I've investigated so far. Anyway, in the Android Virtual Device I go to Settings -> Sound and click on various phone ringtones in order produce some sound, but it doesn't play anything. In Ubuntu Settings -> Sound under volume levels a new entry appears for applications, when they make a sound. The Android Emulator (or anything, like qemu...) does not appear when I play a sound in the Android Virtual Device. Therefore I think this is not a Ubuntu problem, but a problem with the Android Emulator.

In the Virtual Device Configuration I couldn't find anything sound related.

Comment: experiencing the same in Ubuntu 18.04. I think it's not Ubuntu its an emulator bug. A few months before it was working fine